# SVN checkout to other server

Tags: svn, ftp

I have four computers in use:

1. My desktop, on which I write code
2. My server, on which I checkout SVN repositories, test the written code, and commit revisions
3. The SVN server
4. The server I will use in the end

While developing, I'm working on the desktop and the server a lot. When I want to put the latest revision to the end server, I have to do this via FTP, since it doesn't support SVN. So I have to do:

1. Checkout
2. Upload with FTP

It would be useful if I could do this with just one command, like:

1. Checkout to other server with FTP

Is there a command which does that? Or another faster way than what I'm doing now?

Comment: Why do you need ftp? Are there unversioned files? If no, use a ssh connection for the server, go to the desired location and do a svn checkout from the terminal.

Comment: The end server does not have SVN installed and I cannot install due to rights. Or isn't that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ftp mount on your desktop to the server, so you can do the checkout directly from the desktop to the server directory.

Answer (score 0):

Export HEAD + FTP|SCP|RSync to destination in post-commit hook from repository side

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you give me some sample code or a link to that?

Comment: @CamilStaps http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154006/trying-to-write-subversion-post-commit-script-to-export-php-tu-a-public-folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015570/svn-hook-exporting-repo-trouble