# SVN Checkout directly to FTP location

Tags: svn, ftp, tortoisesvn, vcs-checkout

Is it possible to checkout from SVN to FTP location directly either via command line (svn.exe) or via any SVN UI Tool (e.g. Tortoise SVN), as like we can checkout from SVN to any path on local disk OR any network location (either via drive mapping (z:\mynetworkdrive\folder) or directly by starting (\servernane\folder) as like below.

```
C:\> svn checkout http://mysvnserver.com/svn/repository/trunk D:\MyProjectfolder
```

I am looking for this type of command like below

```
C:\> svn checkout http://mysvnserver.com/svn/repository/trunk ftp://myftpserver/htdocs/MyProjectFolder
```

OR

using Tortoise SVN (or any other SVN tool) in right click menu in network location in Windows Explorer.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: AFAIK FTP is not designed to give you random read/write access to a remote file (in difference to SMB/CIFS). While checkout a lot of files in the hidden `.svn` folder have to be updated which requires random read/write access. Therefore a direct checkout to an ftp drive does not seem to be feasible to me.

Comment: From my experience from working on a sftp server, we ran `svn checkout`s like normal, however, we had to do it _on_ the server. But once we performed the checkout on the server, we setup post commit hooks that update the server automatically every time a commit is made so it stays up to date. Unless you're able to actually `cd` into those locations from the command line, I'm going to say that it's probably not possible to do from your client machine.

Comment: Have you try to see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670634/svn-checkout-to-other-server ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new mount on your machine to the server. I'm assuming you're using Windows, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows) for information on how to do that.

Once you've done that, you can use the assigned drive letter to save directly to your server, for example:

```
C:\> svn checkout http://server.com/svn/repo/trunk F:\Your\FTP\Path
```

Comment: Use ‘svn export‘ in this case.